# Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'global'. at line 19 column 1

Tags: apex

```
global class BatchcaseDeleteRecs Implements Database.batchable<sobject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        string s='Enquiry';
        string s1='Junk Mail';
        string query='Interaction_Attribute__c,Interaction_Type__c,Sub_Interaction_Type__c,Status,Case_Last_Closed__c,Case_Last_Time_Resolved__c,Hidden_Case_Opened_Date__c FROM Cases where Interaction_Attribute__c =:s AND Interaction_Type__c =:s1 AND  Sub_Interaction_Type__c =:s1 AND Hidden_Case_Opened_Date__c =Yesterday';   
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Case> scope){

        List <Case>lstcase=new list<Case>();
        for(Case c : scope)
        {
            if(lstcase.size() > 0){
            }
            delete lstcase;

        }
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so many things is wrong in this code.
1. finish method is in execute method.
2. list variable should be like list<>.
3. first line database.batchable should be like this : Database.batchable<sObject>

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error stems from the fact that you are missing a closing brace on your `execute()` method, resulting in the appearance that `finish()` is declared inside it.

This class almost certainly should be `public`, not `global`. `global` is primarily for code in a managed package exposed to code outside the managed package.

Further, however, this logic does nothing at all:

```
    List <Case>lstcase=new list<Case>();
    for(Case c : scope)
    {
        if(lstcase.size() > 0){
        }
        delete lstcase;

    }
```

`listcse` is always empty; the `if` statement has no body; you don't touch `scope` at all; and deleting a list of sObjects in a loop is a bad practice that's also probably not what you want here. Unfortunately, this code is so minimal that I don't have any idea what you actually wanted to do.